# why can i get my initstate recalled whenever the class is recalled by the refresher class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Appreciate your time,so in this code i included the print statements to see what is going on....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    Refresher(),
  );
}

class Refresher extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _RefresherState();
  }
}

class _RefresherState extends State<Refresher> {
  Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(hours: 24),
      (t) => setState(() {}),
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('im the refresher');
    return ScreenTimer();
  }
}

class ScreenTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ScreenTimerState();
  }
}
class _ScreenTimerState extends State<ScreenTimer> {
  _ScreenTimerState(){
    print('state called');
  }
  Timer timer;
  Future<List<String>> runningShow;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Reset urls every 24hrs
    print('im screen timer ');
    runningShow = _getScreen1();
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 30),
      (t) => setState(
        () {},
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

This is my output

```
I/flutter ( 4584): im the refresher
I/flutter ( 4584): state called
I/flutter ( 4584): im screen timer
I/Choreographer( 4584): The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/flutter ( 4584): im the refresher
I/flutter ( 4584): im the refresher
```

Is there a way i can get the initstate called again each time the class  is recalled?because i need the _getscreen(//this function checks database for any changes) recalled after 24hrs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move create a new method that updates you member variable

```
void _updateShowRunning () {
    runningShow = _getScreen1();
}
```

and now call that method in `initState` and periodically.

```
_updateShowRunning();
timer = Timer.periodic(
  Duration(seconds: 30),
  (t) => setState(
    _updateShowRunning,
  ),
);
```

Comment: and in what class do i do this?Screentimer or refresher?

Comment: In you screen timer state (that's where I copied your code from)